# How do I stop sublime text from automatically changing "rb" to "Ruby" when hitting tab?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to write in some comments for this project, but every time I hit the tab button, it automatically changes the files extensions from "rb" to "Ruby"

How do I get it to stop doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Sublime has "tab completion" enabled by default, as described in the config:

```
// When enabled, pressing tab will insert the best matching completion.
// When disabled, tab will only trigger snippets or insert a tab.
// Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is
// enabled.
"tab_completion": true,
```

So you could either set `tab_completion` to `false` in your custom settings, or use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to insert an explicit tab.